# Add a 1-hour expiration to the current time/date

Tags: php

```
//expiration
$datetoday = date("F j, Y, G:i");

$expquery = mysql_query("SELECT a_expire FROM regform_admin WHERE status = 'Pending for payment'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($expquery); 
$expirydate = $row['a_expire'];
echo "$datetoday";
echo "$expirydate";
if ($datetoday == $expirydate) {
    $expirequery = mysql_query("UPDATE regform_admin SET status = 'Expired' WHERE status = 'Pending'");
    $expirequery2 = mysql_query("UPDATE regform SET status = 'Expired' WHERE status = 'Pending'");
}
//end expiration
```

Hi, I have an expiration of reservation code here. My problem is that if a customer makes a reservation on 23:30 and the reservation will expire at 00:30 (1 hour), I made this code:

```
$currentdate = date("F j, Y, G:i");  
$onehour = date("G") + 1;
$expire = date("F j, Y, $onehour:i");
```

The `$onehour` must increment, but the problem is that the 23:30 reservation must expire at 24:30. But after incrementing the $onehour, the 23:30 results into 24:40. Which my program cannot read since military time of 12am is 00:00 and not 24:00. Can anyone have suggestions in my problem? Thanks. Sorry for the lazy english I was tired of thinking

Comment: I hope you realize those update queries will change every row in the table, not just the one you selected.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I am aware of that. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$expire = date("F j, Y, H:i", strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain to me what does strtotime() function is? What is the difference between the one that you posted with this one: $onehour = (date("G") + 1) % 24;

Comment: @glove: To know more about `strtotime`, check the documentations: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @glove If you just modified `$onehour` and it adjusted 24:40 to become 00:40, your new expiration time would be 'today at 12:40AM' instead of 'tomorrow at 12:40AM'... you need to move the whole date 1 hour forward, not just the hour component. `strtotime('+1 hour')` returns a UNIX timestamp of the current time plus one hour, then `date` formats that timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

```
$expire = date("F j, Y, H:i", time()+3600); // 3600 sec in hour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$one_hour_from_now = strtotime('+1 hour');
```

So, all you need is:

```
$expire = date('F j, Y, G:i', strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the current hour is 23 ? Something like (I'm not sure about the PHP syntax of ternary operator though) :

```
$onehour = date("G) > 22 ? 0 : date("G) + 1;
```

Then you also want to change the current day, and check if you change year.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$t = strtotime('2015-10-27 11:19:04');
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );
echo $d . "<br/>";
$t = $t + 3600;
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );
echo $d . "<br/>";
```